# How to record an electrical signal onto a USB

Tags: usb, audio, adc

I'm working on a project which involves being able to record an electric guitar being played directly from the guitar itself without the need of any extra equipment. My idea is to take the audio analog signal (being produced by the guitar pick-ups) and have it saved onto a USB stick that is plugged into the guitar. I've done a bit of research online, and so far I understand that I will have to have an A/D converter before I can save to audio signal to a USB. I am stuck in understanding how to get the digital signal (once converted) to be saved onto the USB.  My idea also involves a switch, in which will toggle on/off when to record - so when it's on, it starts saving the data, and when it turns off again, it finishes recording.

Basically; how to record electrical signal onto a USB.

Comment: Your project needs some development before the problems you face become on topic here. SE is much more geared to Q&A of specific problems and not so much of broad project questions.

Comment: you need a computer with an operating system, to act as a usb host.

Comment: Your best bet for a project like this is to use a Rasperry Pi, or a Teensy or some other similar microcontroller system. It may seem at first like it's making it too complicated, but actually this is the simplest way to get the job done, since you require writing to a USB memory stick.

Comment: Perhaps a USB DAQ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method for this would be to hack a spy audio recorder, or spy camera, or bluetooth transmitter. The first two will record to a mini sd card or built in usb memory. The latter would transmit to a phone or computer that would then record to a file.

Answer (score 0):

The more sophisticated microcontrollers like Raspberry Pi, BeagleBone Black and Teensy are capable of handling high-quality audio (at least 44.1K sample rate and 16-bit depth.)  I found several references for sound recording using RaspBerry Pi. Suggest spending a few quality milliseconds with Google.